# Add the index of the column with the maximum value as a new column

Tags: r, sas, max, apply

My question is simple. When data is as below,

```
var1    var2    var3
10      40      60
15      10      5
```

I want to add a new column `MaxValueVar` that returns index of a column that has maximum value among `var1`, `var2` and `var3`. That is, I want to make a table as below.

```
var1    var2    var3    MaxValueVar
10      40      60      3
15      10      5       1
```

In R I would use:

```
apply(vector, 1, which.max)
```

How can I accomplish this using SAS?

Comment: Is your question asking about how to accomplish this in SAS?

Comment: @Dason Right. Sorry, my question was confusing.

Comment: What do you want to do with missing data? And how do you want to treat ties for the maximum (i.e. - if you have two instances of 60 in the first row)? These will affect the potential answers a bit.

Comment: @thelatemail You're right. But I do not need to care about missing values or tie values as of now. So if presencce of missing or tie values bothers you, just ignore it. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One Solution for your reference according to the sample you provide here. You didn't mention how to deal with ties. Here for ties, the first occurrence is fetched.

```
data test;
input var1 var2 var3;
datalines;
10      40      60
15      10      5
run;

data test;
 set test;
 maxvalue=max(of var1-var3);
 maxvaluevar=0;
  array vars (*) var1-var3;
    do i=1 to dim(vars);
     if maxvaluevar=0 then maxvaluevar=i*(maxvalue=vars(i))+maxvaluevar;
    end;
 drop i maxvalue;
run;
```

Comment: @Robbie_Liu Thank you, Robbie_Liu. But I can not understand "i*(maxvalue=vars(i))". Can you explain more?

Comment: @Robbie_Liu (maxvalue=vars(i)) <- Does this part mean 'If' phrase?

Comment: It could be re-written as `if maxvaluevar = 0 and maxvalue = vars(i) then maxvaluevar = i;`

Comment: @TaeHeonKim Maxvalue=vars(i) returns 0 or 1 on whether a column equals the maximum value. Then by multiplying i, we get the column number. Chris is right. You may find it is easier to understand.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a similar solution to that of Robbie's.  It uses the `vname()` function to get the variable name of the first maximum in addition to the index in the array.

```
data maxarr (drop=i);
input var1 var2 var3;
 array vars(*) var1-var3;
 max=max(of vars(*));
   do i=1 to dim(vars);
     if vars(i)=max then do;
          MaxValueIndx=i;
          MaxValueVar=vname(vars(i));
          leave;
     end;
   end;
datalines;
10      40      60
15      10      5
;
run;

proc print data=maxarr noobs;run;
```

Comment: Thank you, cmjohns. But I have a question. What's the roll of 'leave'? I checked that your code worked appropriately without 'leave'.

Comment: It just stops the loop from continuing on past where we need it to, selecting the first match it sees.  If I did not use `leave` it would process the whole array and the last match would be returned.

Answer (score 2):

The code below should work as intended, as well as creating more columns in the instance of there being ties. I know you said not to bother, but it was bugging me!

Input test data:

```
data test;
    input var1 var2 var3;
    cards;
10 40 60
15 10 5
7 8 9
13 13 10
5 7 6
10 11 12
10 10 10
1 3 2
3 3 1
;
run;
```

Code to check for maximum values:

```
data test (drop = i howmanymax);
    set test;
    retain howmanymax;

    howmanymax=0;

    array varlist[*] var1--var3;
    array maxnum[3];

    do i = 1 to DIM(varlist);
        if varlist[i] = max(of var1--var3)
            then do;
                howmanymax+1;
                maxnum[howmanymax] = i;
            end;
    end;

run;
```

Output looks like:

```
  var1  var2  var3  nummax1 nummax2 nummax3
    10    40    60        3       .       .
    15    10     5        1       .       .
     7     8     9        3       .       .
    13    13    10        1       2       .
     5     7     6        2       .       .
    10    11    12        3       .       .
    10    10    10        1       2       3
     1     3     2        2       .       .
     3     3     1        1       2       .
```

Comment: thank you for your additional help about checking the number of columns that have same maximum values.

Comment: @TaeHeonKim - No problems, glad to help - don't forget to vote and select an accepted answer (not necessarily mine!)